# What is the VC dimension of a Single-Layered Perceptron (SLP) with N inputs?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

What is the VC dimension of a non-linear Multi-Layered Perceptron (MLP) with N inputs and M hidden units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC dimension of SLP is N+1 and VC dimension of MLP is 2(N+1)M(1+log(M))

Thanks